# image upload using html form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on image upload in rails but faced some problems. I have a form that creates a task and has a column for uploading an image. However, when I check the terminal, the form is not sending the image in the parameter so whenever I create a new object, it doesn't include the image. I am using `carrierwave gem` Anybody help me?.

I am new and quite confused with use of Ruby form so I tend to stick to the HTML tags at the moment.

**View** (I didn't include all the code, otherwise it would be hard to read)

```
<form id="new_form" name="task" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control" id="avatar" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @item = item.new(name: params[:name],
                     avatar: params[:avatar])
    @item.save
end
```

Comment: Have you created a `uploader` and mounted the column to the `uploader` ?

Comment: yes I have added `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader` in my model and can see the uploaders folder in my app and inside of the folder, I have `avatar_uploader.rb`, `task_image_uploader.rb`

Comment: Update your question with params that are appeared in the server log hen you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I can't comment, so I will give a try as an answer...
Have you generated the image uploader?
Did you add the `mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader` in your model?
What about your form? 
Can you the show us the way you wrote it? 
It should look this way I believe

```
 # View
<%= form_for @task,  html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :some_title %>
  <%= f.file_field :images %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>  
<% end %>

# Controller

## Action
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  params[:item]['avatar'].each do |avatar|
    @item.avatar = avatar
    @item.save
  end
end

private

def items_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:title, {avatars: []})
end
```

Comment: yes I have added `mount_uploader  :avatar, AvatarUploader` in my model and can see the `uploaders` folder in my app and inside of the folder, I have `avatar_uploader.rb`, `task_image_uploader.rb`

Comment: can you provide more code please? what did you put in your strong parameters?

Comment: I wrote my form like what I have wrote. Do I need to change the form to look like that?

Comment: I am using the html form, does it mean that I can't use `carrierwave`? do I need to convert my form to look like `<%= form_for @task %>` like that?

Comment: You should make your form look like what @NEL has mentioned, and in the controller, check what you're getting in `params` when you submit the form.

Comment: in your tasks controller make sure you have a private methode that looks like  `def tasks_params params.require(:task).permit(:title, {avatars: []}) end `